# ionic paypal error Can't find PayPalConfiguration

Tags: angularjs, paypal, ionic-framework

Refer to [ionic-paypal integration](https://gist.github.com/Urbiwanus/c1e456f889f53e940a11), I added the script to my services.js as a factory and run in my real device.

And I add a js to index.html

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/external/js/lodash.js"></script>

<script src="js/paypal-mobile-js-helper.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

Once I trigger the function:

```
PaypalService.initPaymentUI().then(function () {
  PaypalService.makePayment($scope.total(), "Total").then(...)
});
```

I receive the following error

```
Error: Can't find variable: PayPalConfiguration
configuration@http://{ip}:8100/js/services.js:147:49
http://{ip}:8100/js/services.js:155:83
processQueue@http://{ip}:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27879:30
http://{ip}:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27895:39
$eval@http://{ip}:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29158:28
$digest@http://{ip}:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:28969:36
http://{ip}:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29197:33
completeOutstandingRequest@http://{ip}:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18706:15
http://{ip}:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18978:33
```

// {ip} is my ip address.

PayPalConfiguration should be defined in paypal-mobile-js-helper.js

Edited:

As requested from Martijn Welker, I added more info here:

```
    function configuration() {
        var config = new PayPalConfiguration({merchantName: shopSettings.payPalShopName, merchantPrivacyPolicyURL: shopSettings.payPalMerchantPrivacyPolicyURL, merchantUserAgreementURL: shopSettings.payPalMerchantUserAgreementURL});
        return config;
    }

    function onPayPalMobileInit() {
        $ionicPlatform.ready().then(function () {
            PayPalMobile.prepareToRender(shopSettings.payPalEnv, configuration(), function () {

                $timeout(function () {
                    init_defer.resolve();
                });

            });
        });
    }
```

147:49 is calling PayPalConfiguration in method configuration()

155:83 is calling configuration()

I hope to give you guys ideas.

Thanks for any expert here!

Comment: Could you show us this file/lines ? js/services.js:147:49 - services.js:155:83

Comment: @MartijnWelker alright, please check the additional codes. thanks! it's exactly the code starting from line 76 in the js file referred.

Comment: I think the case can be closed since I put paypal-mobile-js-helper.js into js folder. In my previous understand, the js file doesn't need to be placed to js folder because complier automatically places it during running the app and indeed i can see the js file under js folder after build. Therefore, I haven't had a sense to put my js file there. By the way, I still want to know whether it's correct to do that.